# Angular typeScript nested Array is not iterable?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a model class "EventDeatails" like this

```
export class EventDetails {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  club: string;
  des: string;
  img: string;
  date: string;
  status: number;
}
```

then I assign values to this from firebase like this

```
showingEventList: EventDetails[];

this.eventDetails.getOldEvents().subscribe(actionArray => {
  this.showingEventList = actionArray.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.payload.doc.id,
      ...item.payload.doc.data()
    } as EventDetails ;
  });
});
```

now I need to add only the club property of this object to another array called `clubs[]`
I did it like this

```
for ( const item  of this.showingEventList ) {
      this.clubs.push(item.club);
    }
```

but console shows there is an error:-
" `showingEventList is not iterable` "
how can I fix this ????

Comment: Remember that Observables are async so place for loop in subscribe function. Or You will have for loop of unassigned array.

Comment: Yeh .. that works ... but i didnt get this "Remember that Observables are async "

Comment: Asynchronous check in dictionary ;]